# Why would a webapp need a server online for only a few hours?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

EC2, RDS charge by the number of hours online, but who would actually benefit from this kind of tariff? Why would a webapp need a server online for only a few hours a day/week/etc.?

Comment: Who said that only webapps run on cloud services?

Comment: during high load, you might add an additional instance of a server, then take it down after your peak load had passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hourly tariffs have many use cases.  A big one is scientific research: Astrophysics, Theoretical Computer Science and Mathematics etc.  Traditionally universities would have to pay huge amounts of money for computing clusters to be purchased and installed on-site even though they spend most of their time idle and a small amount of time actually processing data.

With the advent of cloud computing, researchers can launch a huge server cluster and have it crunch over data for a few hours or days, get the results and then terminate the cluster.  See amazon's [high performance computing page](http://aws.amazon.com/hpc-applications/) for more details. You can also read case studies on how [NASA's jet propulsion Lab](http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/nasa-jpl/) and [European space agency](http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/european-space-agency/) make use of flexible tarriff cloud compute clusters on EC2 for processing their data.

Another use case is for auto-scaling. [Amazon's Autoscaling feature](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) allows a load balanced EC2 cluster to be scaled up and down with demand. During heavy load additional servers will be launched and added to the cluster, when load drops again they will be removed. Therefore companies can have massive scalability and only pay for the additional capacity if/when the demand on their web site requires it.

Answer (score 3):

One of the main benefits of cloud deployment is scalability.

For example, if you had an application that served the UK retail industry you might find that your peak usage occurs between 7-9am, 12-2pm and 5-8pm, when your audience are awake/not working.

You may have multiple servers employed during these peak times but only one through the night when traffic is low.

Hourly charging allows for this scalability.